# ERROR ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Tags: sql, oracle

I created the following tables and constraints using [Oracle Live](https://livesql.oracle.com);

- oak_Hotel(**ht_no**, ht_name, ht_city)
- oak_Guest(**gt_no**, gt_name, gt_address)
- oak_Room(**rm_no, htrm_no**, rm_type, rm_price)
- oak_Booking(**htbk_no, gtbk_no, bk_dateFrom**, bk_dateto, rmbk_no)

The constraints are;

- rm_type in oak_room should be restricted to "Single" or "Double" or "Family"
- bk_dateFrom and bk_dateto should not be less than the current date (achieved by implementing a trigger)
- Finally Primary keys and Foreign Keys where appropriate shown above.

The SQL statements used to create the tables and constraints is follows;

```
CREATE TABLE oak_Hotel (
ht_no int NOT NULL,
ht_name varchar(25),
ht_city varchar(25),

CONSTRAINTS PK_hotel PRIMARY KEY(ht_no)
);

CREATE TABLE oak_Guest (
gt_no int NOT NULL,
gt_name varchar(25),
gt_address varchar(25),

CONSTRAINTS PK_guest PRIMARY KEY(gt_no)
);

CREATE TABLE oak_Room (
rm_no int NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
htrm_no int NOT NULL,
rm_type varchar(25),
rm_price NUMERIC(6, 2),

CONSTRAINTS PK_room PRIMARY KEY (rm_no, htrm_no),
CONSTRAINTS FK_guest FOREIGN KEY (htrm_no) REFERENCES 
oak_Hotel(ht_no)
);

ALTER TABLE oak_Room
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Oak_room CHECK ((rm_type='Single' OR 
rm_type='DOUBLE' OR rm_type='Family') AND (rm_price>=100 
AND rm_type<=1000) AND (rm_no>=1 AND rm_no<=100));

CREATE TABLE oak_Booking (
htbk_no int NOT NULL,
gtbk_no int NOT NULL,
bk_dateFrom date NOT NULL,
bk_dateto date,
rmbk_no int,

CONSTRAINTS PK_booking PRIMARY KEY (htbk_no, gtbk_no, bk_dateFrom),
CONSTRAINTS FK_booking_htno FOREIGN KEY (htbk_no) REFERENCES oak_Hotel(ht_no),
CONSTRAINTS FK_booking_gtno FOREIGN KEY (gtbk_no) REFERENCES oak_Guest(gt_no),
CONSTRAINTS FK_booking_rmno FOREIGN KEY (rmbk_no) REFERENCES oak_Room(rm_no)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_check_dates
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON oak_Booking
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.bk_dateFrom < SYSDATE )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 
         'Invalid DA=ateFrom: CloseDate must be greater than the current date - value = ' || to_char( :new.bk_dateFrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
  END IF;
  IF( :new.bk_dateto <= SYSDATE )
  THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 
         'Invalid DA=ateFrom: CloseDate must be greater than the current date - value = ' || to_char( :new.bk_dateto, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
 END IF;
END;
```

The error appears when I try to populate the **oak_room** table `ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721`. The following populates the first 2 tales (oak_hotel, oak_guest).

```
-- Data Entry 
-- ***** Hotel Table *****

INSERT INTO oak_Hotel
VALUES (1234, 'Oak Tree', 'Gaborone');

-- ***** Hotel Guest *****

INSERT INTO oak_Guest
VALUES (1001, 'Sherlock Holmes', '22 Bakers Street');

INSERT INTO oak_Guest
VALUES (1002, 'Donald Trump', 'Twitter Streets');

INSERT INTO oak_Guest
VALUES (1003, 'Iceberg Slim', 'These Streets');

INSERT INTO oak_Guest
VALUES (1004, 'Denise The Menace', '301 Childhood lane');
```

The error pops up when I perform the following statement;

```
-- ****** Hotel Room ******

INSERT INTO oak_Room
VALUES (1, 1234, 'Single', 100.00);

ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue with constraint.

You have used `rm_type<=1000` which is incorrect. It should be `rm_price<=1000`

```
ALTER TABLE oak_Room
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Oak_room CHECK ((rm_type='Single' OR 
rm_type='DOUBLE' OR rm_type='Family') AND (rm_price>=100 
AND rm_price<=1000) AND (rm_no>=1 AND rm_no<=100));
```

Cheers!!