# Cannot insert numeric value into table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have stuck on why i can not insert value into table

`

```
CREATE TABLE Book_Names
(
    BookTitleID number(10)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                NOT NULL,
    BookTitles  varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    Author,
    OtherAuthor varchar2(20),
    Callnumber  number(20),
    CONSTRAINT Book_Names_pk PRIMARY KEY (BookTitleID),
    CONSTRAINT Book_Names_fk FOREIGN KEY (Author) REFERENCES Book_Authors (AuthorID)
);
```

`

`INSERT INTO Book_Names(BookTitles, Author, OtherAuthor, Callnumber) VALUES ('GoodBook', 'Grigor', 'Grigor1', 246);`

ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290769/error-ora-01722-invalid-number-ora-06512-at-sys-dbms-sql-line-1721. Should be the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Apart from invalid `create table` statement (missing datatype for the `author` column) and the fact that we don't have referenced table, that code works OK:

Table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Book_Names
  2  (
  3     BookTitleID   NUMBER (10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  4     BookTitles    VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
  5     Author        VARCHAR2 (20),
  6     OtherAuthor   VARCHAR2 (20),
  7     Callnumber    NUMBER (20),
  8     CONSTRAINT Book_Names_pk PRIMARY KEY (BookTitleID)
  9  --    CONSTRAINT Book_Names_fk FOREIGN KEY (Author) REFERENCES Book_Authors (AuthorID)
 10  );

Table created.
```

Insert:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Book_Names (BookTitles,
  2                          Author,
  3                          OtherAuthor,
  4                          Callnumber)
  5       VALUES ('GoodBook',
  6               'Grigor',
  7               'Grigor1',
  8               246);

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM book_names;

BOOKTITLEID BOOKTITLES           AUTHOR               OTHERAUTHOR          CALLNUMBER
----------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
          1 GoodBook             Grigor               Grigor1                     246

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, either that `insert` didn't raise the error or there's something else wrong. Is there, by any chance, some database trigger involved?

Comment: When i write that SQL > I get Invalid Statement. In another table i insert everything without problems

Comment: Please, post the whole session (just like I did) so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.